# Jenkins: Can comments be added to a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, comments, jenkins-pipeline

Are comments possible in a Jenkinsfile? If so, what's the syntax?

I am using the declarative pipeline syntax.

I want to comment out the "post" section below until my SMTP server is working.

```
pipeline {

  agent { label 'docker-build-slave' }

  environment {
    IMAGE = 'registry.gitlab.com/XXXXX/bible-server'
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS = credentials('DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS')
  }

  options {
    timeout(10)
  }

  stages {

    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn'
        sh 'npm test'
      }
    }

    stage('Build') {
      when {
        branch '*/master'
      }
      steps {
        sh 'docker login -u ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS_USR} -p ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS_PSW} registry.gitlab.com'
        sh 'docker build -t ${IMAGE}:${BRANCH_NAME} .'
        sh 'docker push ${IMAGE}:${BRANCH_NAME}'
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
      when {
        branch '*/master'
      }
      steps {
        echo 'Deploying ..'
      }
    }
  }

  post {
    success {
      mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Yay, we passed."
    }
    failure {
      mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: "Boo, we failed."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you have such language questions about Jenkinsfiles, just remember they are mostly GROOVY scripts.  So it is possible you will find more results if you add the keyword "groovy" rather than "Jenkinsfile".

Answer (score 389, accepted):

The Jenkinsfile is written in groovy which uses the Java (and C) form of comments:

```
/* this
   is a
   multi-line comment */

// this is a single line comment
```

Comment: I am using declarative pipeline on a jenkinsfile inside of an sh section and it fails, perhaps it works on a block level. `pipeline {
...     stage('Set Tagging') {      
      steps {      
      sh '''
          echo "env.m_time='$m_time'" > ${params_file}          
          echo "env.m_comp_tag='${BRANCH_NAME}_${m_time}_${BUILD_NUMBER}'" >> ${params_file}                              
/* echo "env.docker_ws='/usr/local/lib/node_modules/${repo}'" >> ${params_file} */
        ''' < `
  results in error /bash permissions error

Comment: Inside of an `sh` section, you would need to use the shell comment character: `#`

Answer (score 37):

You can use block (/***/) or single line comment (//) for each line. You should use "#" in sh command.

**Block comment**

```html
/*  
post {
    success {
      mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", 
      subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
      body: "Yay, we passed."
    }
    failure {
      mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", 
      subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
      body: "Boo, we failed."
    }
  }
*/
```

**Single Line**

```html
// post {
//     success {
//       mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", 
//       subject:"SUCCESS: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
//       body: "Yay, we passed."
//     }
//     failure {
//       mail to: "XXXXX@gmail.com", 
//       subject:"FAILURE: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
//       body: "Boo, we failed."
//     }
// }
```

**Comment in 'sh' command**

```html
        stage('Unit Test') {
            steps {
                ansiColor('xterm'){
                  sh '''
                  npm test
                  # this is a comment in sh
                  '''
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ugh thanks, forgot I was working within an extended sh block.

Answer (score 4):

The [official Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stage) only mentions single line commands like the following:

```
// Declarative //
```

and ([see](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline))

```
pipeline {
    /* insert Declarative Pipeline here */
}
```

The syntax of the Jenkinsfile is based on **Groovy** so it is also possible to use [groovy syntax for comments](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html). Quote:

```
/* a standalone multiline comment
   spanning two lines */
println "hello" /* a multiline comment starting
                   at the end of a statement */
println 1 /* one */ + 2 /* two */
```

or

```
/**
 * such a nice comment
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments work fine in any of the usual Java/Groovy forms, but you *can't* currently use `groovydoc` to process your `Jenkinsfile` (s).

First, `groovydoc` chokes on files without extensions with the wonderful error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.<init>(SimpleGroovyClassDocAssembler.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.parseGroovy(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.getClassDocsFromSingleSource(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.processFile(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyRootDocBuilder.buildTree(GroovyRootDocBuilder.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyDocTool.add(GroovyDocTool.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.GroovyDocTool$add.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.Main.execute(Main.groovy:214)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.Main.main(Main.groovy:180)
    ... 6 more
```

... and second, as far as I can tell Javadoc-style commments at the start of a `groovy` script are ignored. So even if you copy/rename your `Jenkinsfile` to `Jenkinsfile.groovy`, you won't get much useful output.

I want to be able to use a

```
/**
 * Document my Jenkinsfile's overall purpose here
 */
```

comment at the start of my Jenkinsfile. No such luck (yet).

`groovydoc` *will* process classes and methods defined in your `Jenkinsfile` if you pass `-private` to the command, though.